# Unit testing AngularJS directive, postLink D3 not changing DOM

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, d3.js

I'm trying to unit test an AngularJS directive using Jasmine. The directive is meant to add SVG elements to the template in the postLink phase using D3js. This works fine in the actual application.

In the unit test it appears that the D3 code is never executed.

This is a simplified version of the code that still reproduces the error:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').directive('d3Test', function () {
  return {
    template: '<div id="map"></div>',
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
      someAttr: '@',
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

      d3.select('#map').append('svg');
    }
  };
});
```

This is the unit test:

```
describe('directive test', function () {

  var element, scope;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = '<d3-test></d3-test>';
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$apply();
  }));

  it('should have an SVG child element', function () {
     expect(element.html()).toEqual('<div id="map"><svg></svg></div>');
   });

});
```

The error I receive is:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) directive test should have an SVG child element FAILED
    Expected '<div id="map"></div>' to equal '<div id="map"><svg></svg></div>'.
```

Is my expectation wrong on how I can test for the DOM changes D3 will make?
How can I best test this?

Comment: Hey, to me the line 
element = $compile(element)(scope);
looks weird. Is that intendend ? It looks like you want to pass scope as a parameter.

Comment: nm, apparently that write. But on the AnuglarJS page they use scope.$digest(); insted of apply. $digest triggers an all new cycle ov everything when I recall correctly

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-directives

Comment: @Codebryo, $digest vs $apply doesn't seem to make a difference. If I add scope values in the link function they can be seen by Jasmine, so the code is being executed, only the D3 section doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is very simple.
The `d3.select` method is searching for the element in the `window.document`.
In your test case your element is in a **detached dom element** and not part of the `window.document`.

To fix this you can get the node directly via the directive's element instead of using a global selector.

```
d3.select(element.find('div#map')[0]).append('svg');
```

Note: This code works with angular+jQuery. If you don't use jQuery inside of your project you may need to adapt the selector because then your are limited to lookups by tag name.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Wow this saved my life.  I almost completely gave up testing this d3 code. It saddens when something so simple can cause so much heartache.  But I guess thats what I signed up for when I chose this field.